# Official Documentation for hidden NT driver functions

Tags: windows-nt

I'd love to know where some of the hidden functions that aren't officially in the open kernel are documented.

The current WinAPI and NTAPI documentation lacks these functions.

```
#include <ntapi.h>

Nothing is even documented in the files.
```

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly?  You are asking where to get official documentation for the functions that aren't officially acknowledged to exist?

Comment: *Please tell me where to find the documentation for the undocumented, unofficial, hidden functions.* Does that sound logical to you? You do understand that **undocumented** means **without documentation**, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of functions in the NTAPI that are not documented. Primarily because they could be subject to change at any point during Microsoft's implementation. An example like NtCreateProcess I believe is undocumented. NtQueryProcessInformation. NtdelayExecution. Many many more. One area you can look for undocumented functions is here.
[NtInternals](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSemaphore%2FSEMAPHORE_INFORMATION_CLASS.html) Also reversing kernel modules or even ntdll can help you discover some undocumented functions.